# Is there a method/way to save text data into csv columns with the right formatting as requested?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help on this script that will automatically **scrape** the web and save selected variables as a result. This is the result that I would like to have.

| Collection | Homesites | Bedrooms | Price Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mosaic | 292 | 2 -3 | $557,990 - $ 676,990 |
| Legends | 267 | 2 - 3 | $673,990 - $788,990 |
| Estates | 170 | 2 - 3 | $863,990 - $888,990 |

This is the code that I already have. I was able to save 'collections' in the first column but I am not being able to save the numbers into the rest of the columns (not in the right place). I need help with write the result to the csv file in the correct formatting and the right place which is underneath the headers. Thank you!

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.lennar.com/new-homes/california/sacramento/el-dorado-hills/heritage-el-dorado-hills'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
containers = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'GridItem_container__5PgVU GridItem_item-start-1__1YuAr GridItem_item-span-11__2CVRN GridItem_item-start-md-7__2IvNK GridItem_item-span-md-5__xZ-1p GridItem_item-start-lg-13__2IVYX GridItem_item-span-lg-9__1sQmg GridItem_item-row-2__-d6T5 GridItem_item-row-md-1__20GIi'})
numbers = page_soup.findAll('p', {'class':'Typography_headline3__2nuPh'})

filename = 'product.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w')
headers = 'Collection, Homesites, Bedrooms, Price range\n' 
f.write(headers)

for collections in containers:
    collection = collections.p.text
    f.write(collection + '\n')
    
for num in numbers:
    num = num.text
    f.write(num + '\n') # I need help here
    
f.close()
```

```
#containers look like this after BS4
Mosaic
Legends
Estates

# nums look like this after BS4
292
2 - 3
$557,990 - $676,990
267
2 - 3
$673,990 - $788,990
170
2 - 3
$863,990 - $888,990
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) by pandas? This is a function to save a DataFarme as csv file. And `beautifulsoup` returns DataFrames as far as I know. So you only have to merge your two DataFames.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp thank you i just did. I am still new at this.

Comment: @mosc9575 Yes I am aware of that, I guess my question is how to format them in the right place like my result above. This is what I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution for you:

```
names = [c.p.text for c in containers]
values = [n.text for n in numbers]

df=pd.DataFrame({'Collection':names, 
                 'Homesites':[v for v in values[::3]],
                 'Bedrooms':[v for v in values[1::3]],
                 'Price range':[v for v in values[2::3]],
                })
>>>  df
  Collection Homesites Bedrooms          Price range
0     Mosaic       292    2 - 3  $557,990 - $676,990
1    Legends       267    2 - 3  $673,990 - $788,990
2    Estates       170    2 - 3  $863,990 - $888,990

df.to_csv('product.csv', sep=";")
```

First I do a little re-arrangement to have list with the values per column. Then I create a DataFrame and save this as csv as the last step.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful @mosc9575. One thing, Bedrooms column '2 - 3' turned into 3 - Feb after exported to csv. Is there a way to stop that and just keep '2 - 3' as it?

Comment: This is strange and I was not aware of it. Did you open the 'product.csv' in an editor (mode)? Because in my editor it is correct. Did you open your file afterwards with `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: I opened it in Excel and it turned '2-3' into date format (3-Feb). Wondering if there's a way to stop that within the method to_csv(). I've checked the documentation but no luck. Thinking it might have to do with my Excel setup?

Comment: I see. This is a service/problem by Exel and you can turn it off, [see here](https://www.glidetraining.com/removing-date-formatting-cells-excel/). This is not a problem of pandas. Of course you could also use an other editor.